# Reference group in PySpark multinomial regression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, logistic-regression, multinomial, multiclass-classification

Does anyone know what the default reference group is in a Pyspark multinomial logistic regression. For instance, we have multiclass outcomes/target of `A, B, C, and D`.

How does spark choose the reference category? In standard logistic regression in other software (e.g. `R`, `SAS`) you can set the reference group yourself. So if your reference is `A`, you get `n-1` models fitted together and having the target classes modeled as `A vs B, A vs C, and A vs D`.

You want to control this process because if an outcome with a low number of values (small sample of observation) is set as a reference the estimates are going to be unstable.

[Here is the link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-classification-regression.html#multinomial-logistic-regression) to the multinomial logistic regression model in pyspark. Here the outcome classes are 0, 1, 2 but no clarity on what the reference is. I am assuming it may be zero but not sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that by default, it *does not by use a reference* group. This is why, if you run the snip from your link, you find non-zero values for all intercepts.

From the scala source: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/aggregator/LogisticAggregator.scala

> - Note that there is a difference between multinomial (softmax) and binary loss. The binary case
> - uses one outcome class as a "pivot" and regresses the other class against the pivot. In the
> - multinomial case, the softmax loss function is used to model each class probability
> - independently. Using softmax loss produces `K` sets of coefficients, while using a pivot class
> - produces `K - 1` sets of coefficients (a single coefficient vector in the binary case). In the
> - binary case, we can say that the coefficients are shared between the positive and negative
> - classes...

It goes on to talk about how coefficients are not generally identifiable (which is why one would pick a reference label), but that when the regularization is applied the coefficients do become identifiable.

Comment: This is very helpful. The intercepts are what confused me initially because as you mention we are supposed to have one less intercept than the number of target classes.

Comment: There may be a way to use the "pivot" loss instead of the "softmax" in order to use a reference variable.